# setPersistenceEnabled(true) crashes app when called from BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using this solution:

```
public class FirebaseUtil {
    private static FirebaseDatabase mDatabase;

    public static FirebaseDatabase getDatabase() {
        if (mDatabase == null) {
            mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
            mDatabase.setPersistenceEnabled(true);
        }
        return mDatabase;
    }
}
```

My Application class:

```
public class AnalyticsApplication extends Application { 
  private static GoogleAnalytics sAnalytics; 
  private static Tracker sTracker; 

  @Override public void onCreate() { 
    super.onCreate(); 
    sAnalytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this); 
  } 

  synchronized public Tracker getDefaultTracker() { 
    if (sTracker == null) { 
      sTracker = sAnalytics.newTracker(R.xml.global_tracker); 
    } 
    return sTracker; 
  } 
}
```

I have notifications that makes changes to the database. The notifications are called from a BroadcastReceiver.

The problem is that when getDatabase() if called from the app it is working fine, but when it is called from the notification (different thread) it crashes. When I comment the `mDatabase.setPersistenceEnabled(true);` it is working fine.

Why is that happening and can I fix it?

UPDATE:

Here is the exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 

at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver (ActivityThread.java:3047)

at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap18 (ActivityThread.java)

at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1561)

at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)

at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:154)

at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6119)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)

at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:886)

at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:776)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: 

at     com.mycarservice.mycarservice.utils.DocumentDatabaseHandlerRemote.updateDocument (DocumentDatabaseHandlerRemote.java:48)

at com.mycarservice.mycarservice.utils.NotificationUtils.sendNotification (NotificationUtils.java:43)

at com.mycarservice.mycarservice.utils.DocumentReceiver.onReceive (DocumentReceiver.java:35)

at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver (ActivityThread.java:3040)
```

The idea is that I update the documents when I get notification - in `DocumentReceiver.onReceive` (BroadcastReceiver) I call `sendNotification()` which calls `updateDocument()`.

Comment: share your application class.

Comment: `public class AnalyticsApplication extends Application {
    private static GoogleAnalytics sAnalytics;
    private static Tracker sTracker;
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        sAnalytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
    }
    synchronized public Tracker getDefaultTracker() {
        if (sTracker == null) {
            sTracker = sAnalytics.newTracker(R.xml.global_tracker);
        }
        return sTracker;
    }
}`

Comment: i post solution. check and let me know its working or not.

Comment: Please update your question to include the complete stack trace of the error your get.

Comment: I included the stack trace. Hope it helps you. Please note that when I don't use the `setPersistenceEnabled(true)` it is working without a crash.

Answer (score 0):

> mDatabase.setPersistenceEnabled(true);

getting crash because You have to initialize `firebase` at application level

```
public class MApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

in manifest.xml :

```
<application
    android:name=".MApplication"/>
```

Hope it will help you!!

Comment: I tried this already but very often the application crashes when it was on production. Locally I couldn't reproduce the error but google play console had many crash reports. I tried now to call `FirebaseDatabase.getDatabase();` in my application `onCreate()` but not it is crashing even before I get the notification.